# Why airflow scheduler keeps running my DAG file?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I followed the tutorial, I created a folder $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags, and put the tutorial DAG python file there. I then start the airflow scheduler. By default it is paused. But if I look at the output of airflow scheduler, I saw lot of runs, trying to create the DAGs. Why it keeps running?

```
[2018-09-10 15:49:24,123] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
[2018-09-10 15:49:24,125] {jobs.py:1538} INFO -
================================================================================
DAG File Processing Stats

File Path                                                       PID  Runtime    Last Runtime    Last Run
------------------------------------------------------------  -----  ---------  --------------  -------------------
/Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py  29257  0.44s      0.43s           2018-09-10T13:49:22
================================================================================
[2018-09-10 15:49:24,125] {dag_processing.py:495} INFO - Processor for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py finished
[2018-09-10 15:49:25,133] {dag_processing.py:582} INFO - Started a process (PID: 29258) to generate tasks for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py
[2018-09-10 15:49:25,560] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
[2018-09-10 15:49:25,561] {dag_processing.py:495} INFO - Processor for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py finished
[2018-09-10 15:49:26,567] {dag_processing.py:582} INFO - Started a process (PID: 29259) to generate tasks for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py
[2018-09-10 15:49:26,993] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
[2018-09-10 15:49:27,001] {dag_processing.py:495} INFO - Processor for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py finished
[2018-09-10 15:49:28,009] {dag_processing.py:582} INFO - Started a process (PID: 29260) to generate tasks for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py
[2018-09-10 15:49:28,439] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
[2018-09-10 15:49:28,440] {dag_processing.py:495} INFO - Processor for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py finished
[2018-09-10 15:49:29,445] {dag_processing.py:582} INFO - Started a process (PID: 29261) to generate tasks for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py
[2018-09-10 15:49:29,872] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
[2018-09-10 15:49:29,873] {dag_processing.py:495} INFO - Processor for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py finished
[2018-09-10 15:49:30,876] {dag_processing.py:582} INFO - Started a process (PID: 29263) to generate tasks for /Users/xiang/Documents/BigData/airflow/dags/my_tutorial_2.py
[2018-09-10 15:49:31,309] {jobs.py:1108} INFO - No tasks to consider for execution.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scheduler will "heartbeat" your dag files based on the contents of your `airflow.cfg`. The two settings that probably most relevant to this are:

[min_file_process_interval](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/config/airflow.cfg#L458):  How many seconds to wait between file-parsing loops to prevent the logs from being spammed.

[scheduler_heartbeat_sec](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/config/airflow.cfg#L451): The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).

Consider changing these if you are only running a few DAGs with tasks that are not run very often.

Comment: You ment `min_file_process_interval` ?